# Getting count of a Core Data entity's attributes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a Core Data entity which has `logo` as one of its attributes - I need to check the count of logo, so I can properly set an image view in the cell (i.e. avoid a crash when a new `company` is added and doesn't have a logo). With a hardcoded array of, say, `logos`, it's as simple as `logos.count`, but I'm not sure how to perform the same check on a Core Data entity. What's the best way of doing this?

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if /*What to count?*/.count >= indexPath.row + 1 {
            cell.logoView.image = UIImage(named: (company.value(forKey: "logo") as? String)!)
        } else {
            cell.logoView.image = UIImage(named: "noImage")
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Is `logo` an `Array` or a `String`? From your current code `company.value(forKey: "logo") as? String` it seems like a String, but when you say you need the `count` of logo you make it seem like `"logo"` is an `Array`. Which is it?

Comment: The `logo` attribute is of type `String`. Maybe I'm incorrect in thinking that I need `.count`, I was using that in my previous version of this code (when I was using a hardcoded string array). This is for practice with core data so I may be off track and need something different altogether.

Comment: Could you show us your data model? Usually Xcode creates the default one as `projectname.xcdatamodeld`

Comment: @MichaelFourre done!

Comment: from what I can see based on this data model, I don't see a reason to check `count` for anything. I would just rewrite the statement to unwrap the "logo" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I can see from your current setup, the following should be fine:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if let logo = company.value(forKey: "logo") as? String {
        cell.logoView.image = UIImage(named: logo)
    } else {
        cell.logoView.image = UIImage(named: "noImage")
    }
}
```

Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Worked a charm! Thanks Michael.